# Prevent table updating

Tags: sql-server

I have more tables replicated using transactional replication with push subscription.
How can I prevent users/stored procedures updating those tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user without rights to run that SP or write in that tables and use it as the user for  your needs (run app, etc).